# Ruby processes on OSX keep going above 90%. What's up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, cpu

I have a handful of Ruby/Rails apps I'm building locally.  I've noticed lately that no matter which app I'm working on, my Ruby process will build up to 90+%, the CPU fan will kick on, and there's no stopping it unless I kill the sucker.  Doesn't seem to matter which app I'm working on.  Any ideas?  Any way to track what's wrong?

I've run the apps on Mongrel, Apache/Passenger, and POW, and every time I get the same result.

And BTW I don't have any jobs or tasks running constantly.  This CPU hogging is happening without the servers being hit.

My system:

```
Ruby: ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
Rails: Rails 3.0.4
OSX 10.6.7, MBP 2.53 GHz Core 2 Duo
```

Comment: Occasionally I'll see something like that but it's because I have a stuck Ruby process, often because I was debugging something then closed the shell/terminal window. The machine will be running hot and seem more sluggish. I haven't figured out the entire cause, but it's happened enough times that I do a `top` or `ps aux | grep ruby` to see if something unexpected is running. Back to the question: Without source or config files or `ps` dumps it's hard to say what could be wrong.

Comment: I had *exactly* this days after running a local site preview with Ruby static site generator Nanoc - `top` showed two orphaned ruby processes running at 90+% CPU. I'd started a local (Ruby) preview server, then quit VSCode without first using `ctrl-C` to kill the local server. The two rogue Ruby processes didn't respond to `kill <PID>` so ran `ps -ax | grep "ruby"` to identify the culprits, then used Activity Monitor to force-quite them both. Could have used `kill -9 <PID>` but Activity Monitor was open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried opening a terminal window and running `top`, or opening `Activity Monitor`, then running each one individually and seeing when your CPU starts to climb? Both `top` and `Activity Monitor` will let you sort by the CPU load an app is generating. Use `top -o cpu` and watch to see if the highest load is the app you ran or maybe something else the app is causing to run.

A Rails app will spike when it starts up but should settle down as it waits for incoming connections. If you have periodic tasks it's performing you should see those cause the CPU activity to spike again then drop when the task ends.

You're on a MacBook Pro. How much RAM do you have? Maybe your apps are running low and having to swap out too much? That would affect your overall system performance making the CPU work harder, causing it to heat up. A MacBook Pro's hard disk is designed for battery efficiency, not high performance, so if you're hitting the disk hard with a lot of database I/O, you could be heating the machine up and causing the apps to wait due to record locking or some sort of contention.

There's a lot of different things that can cause your machine and apps to slow down, and you haven't really given us a lot to work with, so those are some general ideas of what I'd look into.

Comment: great post.  i've monitored with activity monitor, but not enough quite yet to really track.  will be keeping it open.  has been all day today, and the current app i'm on hasn't made any problems.  been at a steady 0.3 CPU all day.    i have 8 gigs ram, but that sounds like what could be happening.  i've noticed a general sluggishness when this happens and it could be this.  will keep an eye.  what else can i look out for?  i know i haven't given much but i'd like to know how to debug these types of problems.  thanks again.

Comment: you hit it.  a stuck Ruby process.  i was debugging in console, got into a nasty loop, closed the console, and the ruby shot right up to 99%.  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have noticed this also and was able to pin-point it..  If I run top -o cpu, and then open another terminal window and run IRB, and then close the terminal window without exiting out of IRB, then suddenly top shows a ruby process at around 90% CPU.  If I do the same experiment but exit out of IRB prior to closing the window, there is no 90% ruby hog.

So, apparently we need to be careful to not close terminal windows unless we have properly exited out of ruby programs.

Answer (score 0):

This might be more of a suggestion than an answer, because I don't know if it covers your issue, but it takes just a few minutes, and you might want to try it.

I have had this problem on FreeBSD, and here was my solution. Somehow, the versions of Ruby / Rails / etc were not compatible with one another, and they also did not give me error messages I could always chase down.

I'm sure you are doing this, but make sure your bundle is always up-to-date.

I switched to rvm (Ruby Version Manager), and stopped using system Ruby altogether. This was overall the best sysadmin move I made with Ruby, because Mac OS X / Macports (my dev machine) and FreeBSD / ports (my production machine) are way behind in Ruby versions.

I can see that you are at ruby 1.8.7 patchlevel 174 on Mac OS X -- the current version's patchlevel is somewhere at or above 330.

Moreover, if you are pushing to a production server that's not Mac OS X, then you're going to probably get better portability with RVM, because you can install the same versions of Ruby, Rails, and all gems, on both machines.

Comment: As a note of caution: Do NOT try upgrading the Apple installed Ruby. They put it there for their use and you could break the code that relies on it. Install a new version using RVM, or into `/usr/local` or `/opt`.

Comment: I have this problem and am using RVM, so this answer does not help me.